# ViewModel MVC 5 created using 2 classes, controller which using it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It is not a new topic, however even after reading through many of them, i'm still not fully understand how i can implement them in my case. looking for your advise.

I have two classes.

```
public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Video
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string VideoLink { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
    }
```

At the moment i have two controllers for each of them `MediasController` and `VideosController`, each of them works with `MediaMain` view and `VideoMain` view. In result i can show two objects on two separate views. We are talking about sort of a media blog website, were news may differ, they may be text only,text + image or text + video. Every new "media" should populate on One view.

If we are talking on a high level, i think i should create a new viewModel class to gather into it those fields which i need to show on viewmodel page, right? here is what i have:

```
public class MediaViewModel
    {
        public class Media 
        { 
                public string title { get; set; }
                public string description { get; set; }
                public string body { get; set; }
                public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        }
        public class Video 
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string VideoLink { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Now, if that correct i should have a ViewModelController made of this class, right? Or maybe i need a collection of both classes? 
What i mean is something like this:

```
public class MediaViewModel
        {
            public class Media 
            { 
                    public string title { get; set; }
                    public string description { get; set; }
                    public string body { get; set; }
                    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

                    **public Video Video{ get; set; }**
            }
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: The composition class has properties `public class MediaViewModel { public Media Media { get; set; } public Video Video { get; set; } }`. When you start talking about collections you'll need to consider how each item relates to the other collection.

Comment: You typically do not have a ViewModel controller. You could create a "Media" controller however. A viewmodel is just a container for holding data. Sparrow's answer below is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys!   yes this makes things little bet more clearer

Comment: The solution of this problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256358/viewmodel-mvc-5-2-models-db-controller-view-relationship-understanding) Thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, except your class definition should look like this:

```
public class MediaViewModel
{
   public Media media { get; set; }
   public Video video { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be build this. This is the best practice;

```
public MediaViewModel()
    {
        Foo = new List<Media>();
        FooVideo = new List<Video>();
    }
    public IList<Media> Foo { get; set; }
    public IList<Video> FooVideo { get; set; }
```

Also you can use like this in your controller

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        var model = new MediaViewModel();
        model.Foo.Add(new Models.Media
        {
            body = "test body",
            description = "description",
            ImagePath = "../path/path",
            title = "this title"
        });
        return View(model);            
    }
```

In you view with razor engine you can use like this example.

```
@model TestMVC.ViewModels.MediaViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model.Foo)
{
    <p>@item.title</p>
    <p>@item.ImagePath</p>
    <p>@item.body</p>
    <p>@item.description</p>    
}
```

At the end you will get something like this.
[image: Viewmodel print]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much, i'm going to test it asap!

Comment: good luck with that. please share your test result after your test.

Comment: 1. When i'm creating this new "media", do i need to have a new Create, Update, Delete vews based on ViewModel or i'm creating those
using standart EF create views individually?
2. You show this way of accessing parameters Model.FooVideo.Description but i think i need to use a loop to go through desired parameters of the object don't I? 
Maybe i need somethin like this:   @foreach (var video in ViewBag.video) {} ?

Comment: 1) viewmodels just abstraction for your view between models. Your table must be based on like your video and image classes. 2) yes you are right you should be use loop like foreach. You can use easily with viewbag. If you insist using model, you should be use IEnumerable media and video classes in your viewmodel like this public List<Video> FooVideo

Comment: any chance to give an example please? i cant figure out what is happening in view.