# ViewModel MVC 5 2 models, db, controller view relationship understanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I keep trying to get my head around this whole concept and i could really use your help guys. I'm working from code first approach. I made a post yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241796/viewmodel-mvc-5-created-using-2-classes-controller-which-using-it) but further work based on advises didn't work for me. So to make the problem clear i go over it again.

I have 2 simple classes.

```
 public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; } 
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }        
    }
```

and

```
public class Video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string VideoLink { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
}
```

For each of them i have its own controller and set of CRUD views genereated by EF. So i can create and store this two objects in db, i have a context class for that:

```
public class EventsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Media> Medias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
        }   
    }
```

I have this method im MediasController

```
public ActionResult MediaMain()
{
    IEnumerable<Media> medias = db.Medias;
    ViewBag.Medias = medias;
    return View();
}
```

it accesses stored object from db and allows to work with every field in view. this way.

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Model)
{ 
   @Html.Raw(Model.ImagePath)
}
```

Good and sound, i understand that. BUT. i still have two different views, while i need only one. So i created a MediaViewModel class (thanks for help with that) looking like this:

```
public class MediaViewModel
{
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public Video video { get; set; }
}
```

If i create a method in MediasController looks like this:

```
public ActionResult MediaMain () {
    var model = new MediaViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

i cant access data from objects, as it gives me nullexception, looks like i'm not sending over an object. I think i need to have something like  `IEnumerable<MediaViewModel> medias = db.MediaViewModel;` but i don't have this in my db context, do i need to create one? If so, it would be a collection of object of two classes? That's does not sound right. I need to see what exactly happening in Controller and in view to be able to access all data i need. Pls help.

Comment: check my answer below. Ask anything if any.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model

```
public class MediaViewModel
{
    public List<Media> media { get; set; }
    public List<Video> video { get; set; }
}
```

Your Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult MediaMain () {
    var model = new MediaViewModel();
    model.media = db.Medias.ToList();
    model.video = db.Videos.Tolist();
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.